# Scraping wikipedia infobox geography vcard

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying too scrape the data from the Website section from the various cities' vcard table on wikipedia but somehow I get the results for the Co-ordinates section which is located at the beginning off the table

I have tried specifying "Website" while selecting the specific tags in the table.

```
def getAdditionalInfo(url):
    try:
        city_page = PageContent('https://en.wikipedia.org' + url)
        table = city_page.find('table', {'class' : 'infobox geography vcard'})
        additional_details = []
        read_content = False
        for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
            if (tr.get('class') == ['mergedtoprow'] and not read_content):
                link = tr.find('th')
                if (link and (link.get_text().strip() == 'Website')):
                    read_content = True
            elif ((tr.get('class') == ['mergedbottomrow']) or tr.get('class') == ['mergedrow'] and read_content):
                additional_details.append(tr.find('td').get_text().strip('\n'))
        return additional_details
    except Exception as error:
        print('Error occured: {}'.format(error))
        return []
```

I want to append this data into a new column which shows the website link for each city's official page which I would be getting from this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:contains` to target the table header of `website` and then get the next td's a tag href attribute. Clearly there are other cases where this pattern could match so perhaps some other form of validation is required on input values.

You could add an additional class selector for the vcard if you wish: `result = soup.select_one('.vcard th:contains(Website) + td > [href]')`

Python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

cities = ['Paris', 'Frankfurt', 'London']
base = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    for city in cities:
        r = s.get(base + city)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        result = soup.select_one('th:contains(Website) + td > [href]') 
        if result is None:
            print(city, 'selector failed to find url')
        else:
            print(city, result['href'])
```

Comment: thanks..that worked just fine but it returned 'none' for a lot of cases. I m trying to figure out how to get inside one more <td> tag when such case appears as the <href> tag is sometimes under two tags instead of one.

Comment: can you supply me a couple of those cases?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem correctly, you want to extract official URL of the city from Wikipedia:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getAdditionalInfo(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org' + url).text, 'lxml')
    for th in soup.select('.vcard th'):
        if not th.text.lower() == 'website':
            continue
        yield th.parent.select_one('td').text

cities = ['/wiki/Paris', '/wiki/London', '/wiki/Madrid']

for city in cities:
    for info in getAdditionalInfo(city):
        print(f'{city}: {info}')
```

This prints:

```
/wiki/Paris: www.paris.fr
/wiki/London: london.gov.uk
/wiki/Madrid: www.madrid.es
```